# Can I restrict dmesg to a group?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, group, dmesg, sysctl

I understand that, for security reasons (like address randomization), it makes some sense to not let every user be able to read the kernel's dmesg. Linux allows one to restrict dmesg to the root user using: `sysctl -w kernel.dmesg_restrict = 1`.

That sysctl forces everyone who wants to use dmesg to prepend `sudo`, which is a problem for me.¹

I would like something in between. I want some user accounts on my machines to have sudoless access to dmesg, but not daemons like apache or non-users like www-data.

Ideally, dmesg access would be restricted to a certain group (say, `adm`).

What is the cleanest² way to do this?

---

*Footnotes:*

¹ While I like sudo in concept, I believe it should be a four-letter word: used judiciously by the wise as a perfect epithet for the rare occasions when nothing else would suffice. Unfortunately, I see people using sudo for many mundane tasks nowadays without thinking twice. Getting people into the habit of overusing sudo is a worse security problem than potential address leaks from the kernel.

² I mention "cleanest", because I suspect that some solutions, like `chmod 4750 /bin/dmesg`, might have potentially hairy security implications.

---

**Update**: I've accepted Ikkachu's `setcap` solution, but I hope that in future versions of Linux there will be a cleaner, more general answer. Perhaps a third sysctl setting for dmesg_restrict that is between 0 (everybody) and 1 (root only), that would let sysadmins specify trusted groups.

Comment: I think that part of the problem with `sudo` is that it's often used to simply do what you're not supposed to -- become root (as with `sudo -s`).  I think a reasonable entry in `sudoers` to explicitly allow a specific group to specifically run `/bin/dmesg` is exactly what `sudo` is for.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: I agree that allowing a group passwordless access is a reasonable use of `sudo`, but the problem is people, including me, are getting desensitized to using `sudo`. I want the need for sudo to be so rare that I notice it. For example, I was just looking at the instructions for a program (youtube-dl) which literally says to use `sudo pip ...` to install it. This is insane from a security perspective as it runs arbitrary code as root!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, by "sudoless", you mean you want to be able to just write `dmesg` or such on the command line, then the simplest solution would be to make a script that calls `/bin/dmesg` through `sudo`, and configure sudo to let that happen without asking for a password.

So, something like this:

```
echo 'username ALL = NOPASSWD:/bin/dmesg  ' >> /etc/sudoers
cat <<'EOF' > ./dmesg
#!/bin/sh
sudo /bin/dmesg "$@"
EOF
chmod +x ./dmesg
```

and then put `./dmesg` somewhere in your path.

This works as long as you don't have some other program that needs to be able to read the kernel message buffer directly, without going through `/bin/dmesg`. But then, setting `/bin/dmesg` setuid would have the same limitation. Running it via `sudo` is probably safer than simply running it setuid.

As an aside, changing the permissions on `/dev/kmsg` doesn't work, even though `dmesg` tries to read it. It falls back to the `syslog(2)` system call.

---

If that's not enough, you might be able to do this with [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).
The `dmesg_restrict` sysctl restricts reading the log to processes with `CAP_SYSLOG`, so we just need to arrange for that to be set.

So, something like this:

```
# cp /bin/dmesg /bin/dmesg.capable 
# chown .adm /bin/dmesg.capable
# chmod 710 /bin/dmesg.capable
# setcap cap_syslog=ep /bin/dmesg.capable
```

Users in the `adm` group should now be able to use `/bin/dmesg.capable` to view the log.

Though note that capabilities are notorious in that many of them provide ways to circumvent the rest of the access control systems, though granting just `CAP_SYSLOG` is probably better than running `dmesg` as full root.

---

Other options that spring to mind are SELinux, `seccomp` and just plain old patching the kernel to allow reading the log by a certain group.

Comment: Thanks, but by 'sudoless', I really meant without sudo at all, not even hidden in a wrapper. There are no other answers, though, so I'm beginning to think this is currently impossible in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @hackerb9, right, I thought you just wanted to get rid of the trouble of writing `sudo`, since you said "users need to prepend it". Hiding it behind a script or a shell function removes that everyday nuisance. And really, per-binary targeted privilege is much better than the wide open do what you like that we commonly have. But of course there's the risk that the program has bugs that allow executing other code.

Comment: Thank you, Ikkachu, for updating your answer so thoroughly. I think capabilities is probably the best available solution, so I'll accept the answer.